# Use Apple's usdzconvert on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, macos, executable, usd

I've successfully built [Pixar's USD pipeline](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD) on a Linux VM, and I now strive to accomplish something similar to Apple's usdzconvert from their [USDZ tools](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/tools/).

As of right now, I'm able to run the standard commands from Pixar, such as [usdCat](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/USD-Toolset.html#USDToolset-usdcat), but what I'm missing is an executable that can convert certain formats (such as FBX or USDC) to `.usdz`. Is it possible in some way to import certain files/executables from Apple's tools and use them on my Linux VM? If so, how do I proceed?

Any other tips on how to convert to USDZ (using command line) are appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This seems like it's more appropriate for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Your question is about Linux, but it is not an entirely programming question. Such questions are off-topic here, but they are on-topic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com . Please visit that site and re-ask there.